# Conditional assignemnt in Java

Tags: java, variable-assignment

Is there a good way to do away with null values in java like in ruby there is:

```
x = null || "string"
```

I want to do somthing like this.

```
String line = reader.readLine() || "";
```

To prevent null values being passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no null-safe syntax in Java. You should do it manually. Alternatively, you can create or use an utility like commons-lang:

```
String line = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(reader.readLine());
```

That way you'll get either the value, or "" if it's `null`

Answer (score 12):

You could use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and its <s>[`Objects.firstNonNull`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#firstNonNull-T-T-)</s> method (Removed from Guava 21.0):

```
String line = Objects.firstNonNull(reader.readLine(), "");
```

Or for this specific case, [`Strings.nullToEmpty`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#nullToEmpty-java.lang.String-):

```
String line = Strings.nullToEmpty(reader.readLine());
```

Of course both of those can be statically imported if you find yourself using them a lot.

Comment: Guava is amazing, you should take the time to familiarize yourself with it.  I will not work on a Java project again without it.

Comment: @Bill: I concur absolutely :)

Comment: Is it really worth embedding an entire library to deal with something that simple? Why not just add a line of code to check if your string is null?

Comment: @svz same thoughts here. It is a 2MB library! It is an "enterprise" library from Google. Certainly overkill.

Comment: @svz: Yes, it is - because it gives you *way* more than just that, and once you've made the decision to use it for one thing, you'll find it helps all over the place. For any *one specific thing* it may be overkill - but for the whole combined package, it's wonderful.

Comment: @svz I would say over 60% of all classes I write use Guava.  The connivence methods save a lot of time.  But the data structures are very powerful.  MultiMaps, MultiSets, Free LRU Caches.  I would not use it for a simple program, but anything I care remotely about uses Guava.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  You can assign the result of readline() to a temp variable and then conditionally assign it:

```
String t = reader.readline();
String line = t == null ? "default" : t;
```

but that's about the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` can return null as well. You should just check for null when you need to use the `String`.

Comment: I think that was the point.  If readLine returns null then use empty string instead.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, he stated he wanted something like this: `String line = reader.readLine() || "";` If readLine can return null, and if this construct is allowed, you still can be left with a null. I know Guava and Apache libraries are really good, but we are going to end up soon with applications built with 30 libraries sitting on top of each other. So I still think this is the best answer. Does he really need a 2MB "enterprise" library for this? You all decide.